# How to use apply to generate a data frame row by row?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I want to generate a dataframe row by row, by using some flavor of `apply` on a list of values and a function that returns a single-row data frame for each value. As a toy example, suppose that my values are `i = 1:3` and that I have:

```
f <- function(i) {
    return(data.frame(img=letters[i], cached=F, i=i, stringsAsFactors=F))
}
```

I've been messing around with `sapply`, `lapply`, a bunch of transpose etc. with no success (for example, `d = sapply(1:3, f)` looks promising, but appears to be the transpose of what I want, so I tried `d = t(sapply(1:3,f))`, except that it is a matrix; I therefore tried next `d = as.data.frame(t(sapply(1:3, f)))`, which *appears* right (it prints out just like what I want), but is still wrong, as you'd find out if you try to subset it e.g. `d[,1]` which is in fact a list).

Finally I got this, which works:

```
d = apply(data.frame(i=1:3), 2, f)$i
```

That gives me the frame I wanted:

```
  img cached i
1   a  FALSE 1
2   b  FALSE 2
3   c  FALSE 3
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to express the above?  It all feels pretty kludgy and overly complicated to me.

---

**Edit**: as mentioned by several readers, this "toy example" is admitedly too simple, and indeed just `f(1:3)` would do what it looks like I am requesting. The actual function is part of a web-based metrics dashboard, draws data from various DB tables, and makes moderately complex plots which I intend to cache (most of the time they change relatively slowly). The relevant part, I guess, is that the function typically takes several arguments, and those arguments aren't a simple sequence `1:n`. So, let me rewrite the example to be a tad more realistic:

```
library(digest)
gkey   <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  return(digest(paste(args,sep=".",collapse=".")));
}

f <- function(conn, table, checknew.query, plot.query, plot.fun, params) {
  latest.data = queryExec(conn, table, checknew.query, params)
  key = gkey(table, latest.data, plot.query, plot.fun, params)
  out = getFromCacheOrPlot(key, conn, table, plot.query, plot.fun, params)
  return(out)
}
```

where `queryExec` builds a query, executes it and retrieves the results, `gkey()` computes a hash key based on its parameters, `getFromCacheOrPlot()` uses the `key` to build a file name (a .png image), retrieves it from cache if it exists, or generates it otherwise. It also returns a data.frame with one row giving us the file name, an html `<img=...>` blurb to display it, whether the plot was in or out of cache, and which parameters were used for the plot.

All this is used in a plugin for a wiki system, and certain pages have dozen of plots or more.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(i, f))`  will do what you're asking... but so would `data.frame(img=letters[i], cached=F, i=i, stringsAsFactors=F)`... so I guess I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I think you need a toy example that more accurately represents your really issue, since my immediate response would be to simply do `data.frame(img = letters[i],cached = rep(FALSE,length(i)),i = i)` and I'm guessing that's not what you're after.

Comment: or, since you already made the function `f`:  `f(i)` will produce the data.frame too.

Comment: @Justin: fair enough, the toy example is too simple. The real function is part of a web-based dashboard and actually produces some complicated plot using a database connection. The plots are typically cached on disk, and do not need to be re-rendered depending on certain conditions (decided by the function's logic).  So, I need to make the toy example a bit more realistic, I suppose.

Comment: Your method seems pretty good to me, but I find `do.call(rbind, lapply(i, f))`  somehow clearer ...

Comment: When I work with `sapply`, I often specify `simplify = FALSE` and shape my data by hand (with `do.call`).

Comment: @digEmAll: thank you, I like that solution. Could you or Justin please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I guess priority goes to @Justin ;)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I'd like to highlight your suggestion. I  basically always do that as well. `simplify=TRUE` can be really harmful in particular on edge cases (e.g. one column becomes one vector...) because you're not sure of the result...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`do.call(rbind, lapply(i, f))` will do what you're asking... but so would:

```
data.frame(img=letters[i], cached=F, i=i, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

As would:

```
f(i)
```

Comment: Or use `plyr::ldply(i, f)`

Comment: I might as well, Hadley, since I'm already using plyr and ggplot all over the code that produces the actual plots...

Comment: Hugely helpful and elegant

Answer (score 3):

What about this? No need to use any flavor of `apply` functions

```
foo <- function(x){
  i <- seq_len(x)
  data.frame(img=letters[i], cached=FALSE, i=i, stringsAsFactors=F)
}


  foo(5)
  img cached i
1   a  FALSE 1
2   b  FALSE 2
3   c  FALSE 3
4   d  FALSE 4
5   e  FALSE 5
```

Comment: Sorry but it isn't what I'm after. As indicated in my comments above, the toy example is much too simple; I will rephrase my question.